# Transfering Android Studio files to another PC

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently using android studio to develop an app, but my pc seems pretty bad for it so I'm very afraid that it stops working and i can't access my codes anymore. Is there any way I can transfer the files to another computer? I have the app folder with all the codes, even tried using whatsapp, email and google drive to send the documents but it won't let me. If I buy another computer can I use an external hard drive to transfer my apps to the new computer? Idk if it matters, but i'll be switching from a MacOS to a Windows.

Comment: Highly recommend you put your code on a Git repo, either github.com, gitlab.com or bitbucket.com

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just copy the folder where your project is in to an external hard drive, copy it in the other PC,  install the same version of Android version you are using in the other PC and open that copied folder as a project with Android Studio.

There should be no problem.

Maybe you have also to reconfigure things like Firebase access or the like, but with repeating the process you did it should be enough.

Comment: Thank you! Will be sure to do that than!